# MySQLdump in php exporting 0 size

Tags: php, shell, mysql

Good day people!

I wanted to export a database using shell command in php but I only get 0 bytes. No tables or anything. The code is here:

```
exec('E:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\bin\mysqldump --user=$db_user --password=$db_password --host=$db_host accounts > E:\wamp\www\accountsknc\backups\file.sql');
```

However if I try it in command line, I get a new line:
[image]

Everything is correct here (username, password, database name) except I only get 0 bytes of download. Is there something wrong in here?

**UPDATE:**

Got it working guys.

Instead of `exec('E:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\bin\mysqldump --user=$db_user --password=$db_password --host=$db_host accounts > E:\wamp\www\accountsknc\backups\file.sql');`, I removed the variables and set the username, password and database name directly in the command. Thanks for the help.

Comment: does it work from the command line?

Comment: Do you mean that `E:\wamp\www\accountsknc\backups\file.sql` is empty?

Comment: try to use -u[user] and -p[password]

Comment: @joksnet, you are correct

Comment: @Dagon updated my post using command line

Comment: thats from the mysql command line, mysqldump is its own program

Comment: in your picture do not use mysql> command line...just use the mysql on your shell or windows command line...mysqldump.exe is a file.

Comment: I know that this is your example, but I just want to make sure. Are you adding the `[ ]`s to the actual code?

Comment: In your example you're also using single quotes in your call to exec. That means that your variables aren't getting interpolated and your username is literally `$db_user` and your password is literally `$db_password`.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you're trying to export the accounts table. But it doesn't know what database you're trying to pull it from. The [full doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html) suggests

```
mysqldump.exe [options] database_name table_name > file.sql
```

For clarification, your code would look more like this:

```
<?php
$command = 'E:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\bin\mysqldump.exe';
$password = 'secret';
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$user = 'root';
$dbName = 'accounts';
$fileName = 'E:\wamp\www\accountsknc\backups\20160312.sql';

exec("$command -u $user -p$password -h$host $dbName > $fileName");
```

Comment: should it be really mysql_dump instead of mysqldump?

Comment: Whoops, no. I fixed it, that was just a spelling error of sorts.

Comment: try this
goto this directory "E:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\bin\"
then type "dir" look for mysqldump.exe if there is.

if there is a file mysqldump.exe 

try this

E:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\bin\mysqldump -u[user] -p[password] [dbname] > [your output_filename]